# Step progress bar - lines in between progress numbering box

Tags: html, css

I would like to make the lines in between steps longer or maybe stick on the boxes. I tried to change this css ***.bullet.completed::after*** but it doesn't work. The reason I set width as 100% is because I want it to be responsive.

I've attached snippet here. Can somebody please help me with this? Thanks in advance!

```js
const previousBtn = document.getElementById('previousBtn');
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('nextBtn');
const finishBtn = document.getElementById('finishBtn');
const content = document.getElementById('content');
const bullets = [...document.querySelectorAll('.bullet')];

const MAX_STEPS = 4;
let currentStep = 1;

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  bullets[currentStep - 1].classList.add('completed');
  currentStep += 1;
  previousBtn.disabled = false;
  if (currentStep === MAX_STEPS) {
    nextBtn.disabled = true;
    finishBtn.disabled = false;
  }
  content.innerText = `Step Number ${currentStep}`;
});


previousBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  bullets[currentStep - 2].classList.remove('completed');
  currentStep -= 1;
  nextBtn.disabled = false;
  finishBtn.disabled = true;
  if (currentStep === 1) {
    previousBtn.disabled = true;
  }
  content.innerText = `Step Number ${currentStep}`;
});

finishBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  location.reload();
});
```

```css
#stepProgressBar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.step {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
}

.step-text {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

.bullet {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: background-color 500ms;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.bullet.completed {
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
}

.bullet.completed::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -60px;
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}


/* Base styles and helper stuff */

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

button {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: 250ms background-color;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

button:disabled:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="stepProgressBar">
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Super Duper Long Title</p>
      <div class="bullet">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Long Long Title</p>
      <div class="bullet">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Loooong Title</p>
      <div class="bullet">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Title</p>
      <div class="bullet ">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <p id="content" class="text-center">Step Number 1</p>
    <button id="previousBtn" class="hidden"></button>
    <button id="nextBtn">Next</button>
    <button id="finishBtn" class="hidden">Finish</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the CSS `calc` function to find the sweet spot for the line lengths. The calculation: `width: calc(133% - 21px);`.

The `21px` part of the calculation is:

- half of the number width (`20px` / 2 = 10)
- `4px` for the borders of the adjacent boxes
- `7px` left margin to move the line away from the center of the box.

I'm not sure yet why `133%` is working . In addition, I removed the `position: relative` from the `.bullet` class and moved it to the `.step` parent.

```js
const previousBtn = document.getElementById('previousBtn');
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('nextBtn');
const finishBtn = document.getElementById('finishBtn');
const content = document.getElementById('content');
const bullets = [...document.querySelectorAll('.bullet')];

const MAX_STEPS = 4;
let currentStep = 1;

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  bullets[currentStep - 1].classList.add('completed');
  currentStep += 1;
  previousBtn.disabled = false;
  if (currentStep === MAX_STEPS) {
    nextBtn.disabled = true;
    finishBtn.disabled = false;
  }
  content.innerText = `Step Number ${currentStep}`;
});


previousBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  bullets[currentStep - 2].classList.remove('completed');
  currentStep -= 1;
  nextBtn.disabled = false;
  finishBtn.disabled = true;
  if (currentStep === 1) {
    previousBtn.disabled = true;
  }
  content.innerText = `Step Number ${currentStep}`;
});

finishBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  location.reload();
});
```

```css
#stepProgressBar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.step {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
}

.step-text {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

.bullet {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 500ms;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.bullet.completed {
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
}

.bullet.completed::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 1px;
  width: calc(133% - 21px);
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: 7px;  
}


/* Base styles and helper stuff */

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

button {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: 250ms background-color;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

button:disabled:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="stepProgressBar">
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Super Duper Long Title</p>
      <div class="bullet">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Long Long Title</p>
      <div class="bullet">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Loooong Title</p>
      <div class="bullet">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Title</p>
      <div class="bullet ">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <p id="content" class="text-center">Step Number 1</p>
    <button id="previousBtn" class="hidden"></button>
    <button id="nextBtn">Next</button>
    <button id="finishBtn" class="hidden">Finish</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wrfpL1gd/)

Comment: is it possible to remove half of the line being showed in the box?

Comment: @StacieT. Fixed. I'll update the description of the fix as well.